# Template specialization in .cpp file + primary template declaration in .h file

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization

According to https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#7:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized, a declaration of that specialization shall be reachable from every use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Therefore I wonder, is the following program ill-formed, NDR?

```cpp
// foo.h
template <typename T>
void foo();

// Specialization not declared in the header!

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

template <>
void foo<int>()
{
 // ...
}

// main.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that had it been explicit instantiation instead, [the code would have been well formed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp#pre-10). I guess implementations are allowed to mangle explicit specializations differently.

Comment: "shall" in the standard means "must" or "is required to". So you already have the answer in your quote of the standard. The explicit template specialization in `foo.cpp` has no declaration, that is reachable from the use in `main.cpp`. So yes it is ill formed.

Comment: An interesting variation is: what if we add an explicit instantiation _declaration_ of the `foo<int>()` spec. after the declaration of the primary template in `foo.h`? It seems to be the reasonable thing to do to highlight that the instantiation definition shall not be implicitly instantiated. Or, formally, to highlight that there is in fact a _reachable_ explicit instantiation definition elsewhere, meaning the `foo<int>()` is a _declared_ specialization and shouldn't be implicitly instantiated anywhere. However [\[temp.spec\]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.spec#5.3) ...

Comment: ... makes no different on explicit instantiation declarations/definitions when requiring _"both an **explicit instantiation** and a declaration of an explicit specialization shall not appear in a program **unless the explicit instantiation follows** a declaration of the explicit specialization."_.

Comment: @dfrib: Why wouldn’t you use a (non-defining) explicit specialization declaration, which says what you mean and works?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes that would be the reasonable thing to do. I don't remember why I was interested in the explicit instantiation declaration approach when the "follows elsewhere" is this Q&A is an explicit specialization definition (and not an explicit instantiation definition).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this exact case is covered in the standards committee's "Closed Issues List", which you can read [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#2138), very hard to get more authoritative than that.

TL;DR:

> Rationale (March, 2016):
>
> As stated in the analysis, the intent is for the example to be ill-> formed, no diagnostic required.

Note that you can find quite a few SO questions that are pretty similar to this. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150890/calling-function-templates-specialized-in-another-translation-unit) for example, in which one answerer cites the working group discussion.

Answer (score -1):

> Therefore I wonder, is the following program ill-formed, NDR?

It is. This is `main.cpp` after all the pre-processing:

```cpp
template <class> void foo(); // forward declaration of templated entity

int main() {
  foo<int>(); // Implicit instantiation: Ill Formed; No diagnosis required.
}
```

You might get a linker error like: `undefined reference to 'void foo<int>()'`.
You might not get an error (pre-compiled header, dynamic library...)

Why is diagnosing not required?
Phase 4: Preprocessing (the code above is formed during this phase)
Phase 7: Compilation (producing translation units)
Phase 8: Template instantiation occurs
Phase 9: The last one. This is when the function definition is found (or not) and linked to the executable

See: [Translation Phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)