# explicit template specialization with no explicit specialization declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

I have small example code:

file foo.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

template <typename T> class FooNoDef {
public:
  void foo(const T& value); // declared and not defined
};

class FooUser {
public:
  template <typename T> static void useFoo(const T& value) {
    FooNoDef<T>{}.foo(value);
  }
};
```

file xy.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

struct X {};
struct Y {};
```

file xy.cpp:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "xy.h"
#include <iostream>

template <> void FooNoDef<X>::foo(const X& value) {
  std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
}

template <> void FooNoDef<Y>::foo(const Y& value) {
  std::cout << "y" << std::endl;
}
```

and finally main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "xy.h"

int main() {
  FooUser::useFoo(X{});
  FooUser::useFoo(Y{});
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with gcc 11 and clang 13. I suspect my code is ill-formed, but I can't find a definite answer from reading the standard:

Section 13.9.4 [temp.expl.spec] (emphasis mine):

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
> explicitly specialized, a declaration of that specialization shall be
> reachable from every use of that specialization that would cause an
> **implicit instantiation** to take place, in every translation unit in
> which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. If the program
> does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and
> either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an
> **implicit instantiation** to take place or the member is a virtual member
> function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. An
> implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit
> specialization that is declared but not defined.

Section 13.9.2 [temp.inst] (emphasis mine):

> [Example 5:

```cpp
template<class T> struct Z {
  void f();
  void g();
};

void h() {
  Z<int> a;         // instantiation of class Z<int> required
  Z<char>* p;       // instantiation of class Z<char> not required
  Z<double>* q;     // instantiation of class Z<double> not required

  a.f();            // instantiation of Z<int>​::​f() required
  p->g();           // instantiation of class Z<char> required, and
                    // instantiation of Z<char>​::​g() required
}
```

> **Nothing in this example requires** class Z, Z​::​g(), or **Z​::​f()** to be implicitly instantiated.** — end example]

I think `FooUser::useFoo()` does not cause implicit instantiation of `FooNoDef::foo()` as the example from the standard discussed, but still I never provided a declaration for my explicit specialization of `FooNoDef<X>` and `FooNoDef<Y>`. Which rule of C++, if any, do I violate with my example? Would I have to provide explicit specialization declaration `template <> void FooNoDef<X>;` and `template <> void FooNoDef<Y>;` strictly before the body of `FooUser::useFoo()`?

Comment: (Almost?) duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335712/template-specialization-in-cpp-file-primary-template-declaration-in-h-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are right, though you've put emphasise on the wrong line of the standard:

> [...] a declaration of that specialization shall be reachable from every use of that specialization [...]

Within `main`, both of `FooUser::useFoo<X>` and `FooUser::useFoo<Y>` need to be instantiated. These then need to instantiate `FooNoDef<X>::foo` and `FooNoDef<Y>::foo` – and here an implicit instantiation would be caused, *if* no explicit instantiation was available.

However, there only exists a definition within `xy.cpp`, and that's not visible to `main.cpp`, and there's no visible declaration – violating above cited phrase, thus your programme indeed is ill-formed.

To fix, you'd need to add a declaration, e.g. in `xy.h` (note: the header that is included by `main.cpp`):

```
template <> void FooNoDef<X>::foo(X const& value);
template <> void FooNoDef<Y>::foo(Y const& value);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would anything change in the reasoning you provided if I removed `static` from `FooUser::useFoo()` and changed main: `FooUser fooUser{}; fooUser.useFoo(X{}); fooUser.useFoo(Y{});`?

Comment: @pjk The function is called, so it needs to be instantiated – and together with the function the used template needs to be instantiated – now way around and totally independent from being static or not. Could be a free standing function as well, still wouldn't change. For all these cases, the declaration needs to be available as specified by the standard. It isn't, so ill-formed programme.